# Sending position updates from server to clients (Unity + gRPC)

Tags: unity, networking

So clients connect to the server and the server spawns an entity for each of them. What I'm confused about is how to send position updates from the server to the connected clients. I read about bidirectional streaming but I'm confused because that would mean clients would have to specifically request the positions every update, which is not what I want. I want the server to send positions to every connected client. Is it possible to do it with gRPC? If so, how would I go about it?

Comment: what type of game you are developing? is this real-time or turn-based. as i know grpc is a tcp RPC that doesnt work in real-time. as you want to set position i think you working on a realtime game. so you dont need grpc

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you for your help.

Comment: if its a real-time i can give you right library for this

Comment: I'd be glad if you could

Comment: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/multiplayer/blob/master/com.unity.transport/Documentation~/TableOfContents.md

Comment: its what you are looking for but there are simpler solutions. maybe photon is a easier solution but this is unity latest solution that gives much freedom

Comment: It's good, I'll check it out. Thank you very much!